# Elements selection without dates in R

Tags: r, select, time

Given a matrix `X` of daily asset prices that includes some `NA`, and a dates column as the first one. Now I need to create a function for the time series. One of the steps of this function must be to substitute elements of X that are below `1*e^(-8)` with `NA`.  Now my problem is to select those data without using double `for` function and an `if`. I would like to keep it as simpler as possible ( in a compact way )

I found a solution like :

```
X[is.na(X)] <- 0

X[, 1] <- 0

X[X < 1*e^(-8)] <- NA
```

But I don't think substituting dates column with 0 values is very correct and there must be another way. I'm sure you know it :D

Comment: Why are you making the dates column all 0 at all? That doesn't make sense to me. If you have both dates and values you should be using a `data.frame` not a `matrix`, so you can store the dates as `Date` class, and the values as `numeric`.

Comment: `1*e^(-8) Error: object 'e' not found`. It should be `exp(1)^(-8)`.

Comment: Everything is stored as a data.frame but still if I don't mask the dates when it checks the values it gives me the warning : '<' not meaningful for factors.